# AWS DNS Setup after EC2 removal of the EC2 e-mail sending limitations on your Amazon Web Services account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

This is the mail that i got from Amazon. Then, i did not know how to do  forward DNS record mapping .

> We've reviewed and approved your request for the removal of the EC2
>   e-mail sending limitations on your Amazon Web Services account. There
>   are no longer limitations on your account for any IPs and instances
>   under your account. If you requested removal of e-mail sending limits
>   on Amazon Elastic IPs, they've also been removed.
>
> Because reverse DNS record entries are commonly considered in
>   anti-SPAM filters, we recommend assigning a reverse DNS record to the
>   Elastic IP address you use to send email to third parties. Please use
>   the form located at this link to request a reverse DNS entry:
>
> https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request
>
> Note that a corresponding forward DNS record mapping only one domain
>   to one Elastic IP address must exist before we can create the reverse
>   DNS record on our side.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/html/as400/v4r4/ic2924/info/RZAISFRMPD.HTM) should be able to clarify your doubt

Extracts from it:

**Forward mapping primary domain**

The forward mapping primary domain contains the host names of the hosts in the domain, and the IP addresses that are mapped to the names. Forward mapping primary domains store host name and IP address information as DNS resource records called address records.

**Reverse mapping primary domain**

Reverse mapping primary domains contain IP addresses, and the host names that are mapped to them. Reverse mapping primary domains store host name and IP address information in the form of DNS resource records called pointer records. DNS identifies pointer records as PTR records.